# How do I display a contour plot for my eigenvalue function

Tags: r, matrix, contour

Code for image is below:

````
P <- function(v){
      x <- v[1]
      y <- v[2]
      return(
      sum(eigen(matrix(c(
        5,y,x,
        y,2,1,
        x,1,x),3,3,byrow=TRUE))$values))
    }
    
    xgrid <- seq(from=1, to=6, len=6)
    ygrid <- seq(from=1, to=6, len=6)
    jj <- expand.grid(xgrid,ygrid)
    
    
    M <- apply(jj,1,P) # apply the function f() to jj
    M <- matrix(M,6,6)
    str(M)
    M
    
    
    contour(xgrid,ygrid,M,asp=1,xlim=c(1,6),ylim=c(1,6))
```
````

The above code creates the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6ZmY.png)

Why does the image show the line in the upper right not completely straight?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

The function is already working.  The plot looks bad because both x and y go from -3 to 3, but you have plot limits set to run from 1 to 6.  Remove those, and you get the following:

```r
P <- function(v){
  x <- v[1]
  y <- v[2]
  return(
    sum(eigen(matrix(c(
      5,y,x,
      y,2,1,
      x,1,x),3,3,byrow=TRUE))$values))
}

xgrid <- seq(from=-3, to=3, len=6)
ygrid <- seq(from=-3, to=3, len=6)
jj <- expand.grid(xgrid,ygrid)

M <- apply(jj,1,P) # apply the function P() to jj
M <- matrix(M, 6,6)

contour(xgrid,ygrid,M,asp=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It's not obvious from the function definition, but in fact your function doesn't depend on `v[2]`, so the contours are vertical lines.  This is a property of the sum of eigenvalues:  it is the trace of the matrix, and y doesn't appear in the matrix diagonal.

Comment: when I change v[2] the sum of the eigenvalues stats the same. Is that why the contour plot looks funny?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: I fixed the margins with: 
contour(xgrid,ygrid,M,asp=1,xlim=c(1,6),ylim=c(1,6)). however my contour plot shows a slight kink in 13 line. Why is that? is it not completely independent. I've updated the graph in the post to show you

Comment: You've added a plot to the question, but I don't think the code in the question produces that plot, so I can't really suggest what happened.

Comment: edited the post to have the code that creates the image. I've tried manually testing Y when x=6 and it always = 13 to 10+dp so it does not appear to be slight rounding error.

Comment: It's rounding error in the contouring.  The smallest and largest x values are exactly on contours, so sometimes rounding leads to the contour being dropped.  Use `xgrid <- ygrid <- seq(from=0.9, to=6.1, len=6)` and things will be more stable.

Comment: You can see where the points are by running `points(jj)`.